# Shutting down kvm guest without acpi

Tags: kvm, virsh

I've got a KVM guest that won't shut down from virsh or from virt-manager. Most everything I've read says to install ACPI on the guest and do a bunch of configuring on the host to make this work. Is there any reason that I can't halt the guest from a shell running in the guest and then do the "virsh shutdown " command from the server? I want to avoid "virsh destroy" as I understand that "pulling the plug" is a bad idea, i.e. could corrupt the disk.

Comment: if the VM is halted, it should be safe to `virsh destroy` it -`virsh shutdown` won't have any more effect in halted stated than it will in running state.  The **correct** solution is to get ACPI working on the guest, and there's no  good reason not to do that.

Comment: There is nothing to "configure", just make sure you have the acpi packages installed and enabled inside the guest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using debian as KVM guest. It has qemu-guest-agent package that install guest agent without a pain. On the libvirt side I need to add small chunk of xml configuration to enable it:

```
<channel type='unix'>
  <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/f16x86_64.agent'/>
  <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
</channel>
```

From now on you can use `virsh shutdown --mode agent` to shutdown the guest gracefully